# How to wake up monitor from bash?

Tags: screensaver

I've got screensaver set to 5m `xset s 300` and I need to wake up monitor(suppress screensaver) in 1 hour from bash script. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.redhat.fedora.general/385326

Install the xdotool package (available on F11...not sure if F14 has it)
and then use one of the commands to move the mouse.

Comment: It is available in Fedora 19.

Comment: Are you *really* running Fedora 11?! That one is some 5 years old, and *long* out of support of any sort.

Comment: I'm not using Fedora 11, I'm just citing guy that few years ago was using Fedora 11. My current OS is Arch Linux.

Comment: xwit should also work, if moving the mouse is all you need to do to wake it up.